# FLOSS solution for code-signing server (Windows)

Tags: windows, service, windows-services, code-signing

Does anyone know of FLOSS solutions that allow me to send packages of files to a remote code-signing server for signing? Currently the method is to log into the remote machine using SSH or RDP. Having a dedicated service for this would probably make it easier to integrate into the build process. The important part is that the authentication method has to be secure.

Comment: Do you need an existing solution, or can you do some server-side scripting?

Comment: @Rudi: server-side scripting would be doable, of course. But right now I am looking for an existing solution first of all. Why reinvent the wheel if someone else already did ;)